# UICollection spacing not working I Don't wont any spacing in uicollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

[image]

I have tried following but not working

```
 self.hCltVw.constant = (rowHeight * 8.0)
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: size, height:rowHeight)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        collectionView.reloadData()
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

But still spaing in collectionview row. Dont know why spacing is not working also if i add + 80 in collectionview height spacing is automatically removed.

My Xib Setup

[image]

> NOTE: the strange thing is if I increase collection-view height
> constant then space is decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem, i solved it by this may be it will helpful for you .

in storybord select your collectionview and change some settings in attribute inspector.

- set estimate size = none
- in section insets top,bottom,left,right set this all value 0
- set min Spacing (for cell , for line both) = 0

[edited]

try this:-

```
let width = (view.frame.size.width) / 3
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
```

Comment: can you send image of attribute inspector

Comment: i have added in question please check

Comment: did you select layout = flow in storybord

Comment: what happen if you give static height ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223873/discussion-between-jaydeep-vyas-and-shivam-parmar).